# mov(iphone format) videos not playing in html5 player firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-video, video-player, mov

I am trying to play mov video in [HTML5 Video Player](http://www.videojs.com/) inside lan in firefox(computer) browser but getting the following error:

> no video with supported mime type found firefox

However, at my machine(I am hosting the files) it works well in firefox. In console(at other machines), I see the following warning message:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/quicktime" is not supported.

I have already added the following in .htaccess:

```
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg
AddType video/quicktime .mov
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a .m4b .m4r
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/playlist .m3u
AddType audio/x-scpls .pls
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/wav .wav
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Firefox for iPhone? Or is the iPhone tag just a mistake?

Comment: No no, firefox of pc. Let me edit my question